# Find and prove the supremum of the following set: $S=\{\frac{n-1}{n^2+5}:n>1, n\in\Bbb N\}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, optimization, fractions, supremum-and-infimum

We are given the following set:

$$S=\left\{\frac{n-1}{n^2+5}:n>1, n\in\Bbb N\right\}$$

By using the monotonicity argument, I have found that the sequence is increasing when $n \le3$ and decreasing when $n \ge4$. Therefore, its largest value is $x_n = 1/7$. Is my argument correct and how can I prove this assumption?

I am trying to show that for any fixed $\varepsilon$>0, we should have that $\frac{n-1}{n^2+5} > 1/7 -\varepsilon$, but I am currently stuck at this step.

Comment: Just write it as $\frac{n-1}{n^2+5}=\frac{1}{7}-\frac{(n-3)(n-4)}{7n^2+35}$. This shows both that it is always (for $n\in\mathbb{N}$) less than $1/7$, since the term being subtracted is always $\geq0$, and that you get $1/7$ for $n=3$ and $n=4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer "The sequence is increasing when $n \leq 3$ and decreasing when $n \geq 4$" is not by itself enough: it doesn't tell you what happens between $n=3$ and $n=4$. However, assuming you've done the calculations, you should have found that actually the value is the same ($\frac{1}{7}$) at both those points. So you're right in your conclusion.

The above has shown that $\frac{1}{7}$ is an upper bound for the sequence; strictly speaking, you need to show that it is the *least* upper bound. However, that's clear because the sequence actually attains that value. No upper bound for a sequence can be lower than some specific member of the sequence.

---

For examples of why you need to have done that little bit of extra work: the sequence $1,2,3,2,2,2,\dots$ has supremum $3$, which it attains at $n=3$. The sequence $1,2,3,6,5,4,3,2,2,2,\dots$ has supremum $6$, which it attains at $n=4$. Both these sequences satisfy the requirement that the sequence be increasing on $n \leq 3$ and decreasing on $n \geq 4$.

Comment: Thanks! I got the idea. But how can I rigorously prove this by using the epsilon definition?

Comment: Can I clarify: you're satisfied that every value of the sequence is less than or equal to this purported supremum, and now you wish to show that it is indeed a supremum in the sense that there are no smaller upper bounds?

Comment: Yes, that's where I am stuck at the moment.

Comment: I've edited something in to address that; to use $\epsilon$ is definitely overkill here. You can show directly that anything smaller than $\frac{1}{7}$ fails to be an upper bound for the sequence, because (for instance) the third member of the sequence is bigger than the "upper bound" you're trying.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(n)=\frac{n-1}{n^2+5}.$

You proved that $f(3)\geq f(n)$ for all $n\leq 3$ and  $f(4)\geq f(n)$ for all $n\geq 4$, which says that $$\max\{f(4),f(3)\}=f(3)=\frac{1}{7}$$ is a maximal value.